# Whats the best way to seal a new garage roof to another existing garage roof?

Tags: walls, roof, waterproofing, building

I've just raised my garage roof from just below to 150mm above the adjoining garage of my neighbour. Their felt roof used to flap down onto my roof but now I need to direct this felt flap up to my - what in effect will be an upstand. This flap is only 75 - 100mm so I fear it wont quite be long enough to seal against my my roof.  I will probably be installing an edpm covering which will flap down "over" this upturned flap of my neighbour.

Will bending their flap from down to the upward direction  ruin their felt fabric (its been laid down for 2 or 3 years), what is of the best way to seal it all? Their roof actually slopes in the direction of my garage, somewhat, as a result of some subsidence.

Comment: A photo would really be helpful here I understand what you are asking but the wrong advice can have you and your neighbor at war with each other.

Comment: Are your houses connected?     Or just the roofs are sloped towards each other?   It's not at all clear how the water used to drain off either roof.